# 32bit アプリケーションの参照が　system32からwow64にリダイレクトされていない

Tags: windows, .net

VisualStudioで作成した32bit アプリケーションを実行したところ、動作が停止しました。
ダブルクリックで実行した直後に××の動作は停止を停止しました、とメッセージが表示されます。

以下にある、%UserProfile%AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive
を確認したところ、32bitアプリにもかかわらず、system32のdllを読みこみんでいました。

```
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

①32bitアプリケーションは以前は問題なく動作していました。
②上記の問題は実行環境をクラウド（AWS）に移行しようとした際に発生しました。（OSは変更していません）
③同様の環境移行を64bit アプリケーションで行っていますが、問題なく動作しています。
④また、問題なく動作する環境で、意図的にエラーを発生させた場合、%UserProfile%AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive　のログではWow64を読み込んでしました。

```
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
```

以上のことから、wow64を読み込んでいないことが原因ではないかと推測しています。

msdnのファイルシステムリダイレクタに関する記述を読んだのですが、問題発生の原因、対応法がわかりませんでした。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector

対応方法ご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

ちなみに、実行環境は
AWS　EC2　m5.xlarge
WindowsServer 2012R2
です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NETアプリケーションはCPUネイティブのコードが含まれておらず、実行時にコード生成を行うため、特定のCPUには依存していません。[`CorFlags.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool)を使用することで当該バイナリの設定を確認することができます。

```
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
```

と表示された場合、32bitを要求せず32bitを優先しないため、64bit OSでは64bit実行されます。どちらかが`0`以外の場合には64bit OSであっても32bit動作します。